# Fetching data from a MySQL database using Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have written JavaScript code for fetching data from a MySQL database. I have used connection pooling and Promise API.

```
var mySql = require("mysql");
var Promise = require("promise");

var pool = mySql.createPool({
  host : "localhost",
  user : "root",
  password : "rahul",
  database : "testDb", //schema 
  connectionLimit : 13, // at a time 13 connection be created in pool
});

function getDepartments(){
  return new Promise(fn);

  function fn(resolve,reject){
    pool.getConnection(function(err,con){
        if(err){
            return reject(err);
        }else{
            con.query("select * from departmentTbl",function(err,rows){
                if(err){
                    return reject(err);
                }else{
                    con.release(); // releasing connection to pool
                    return resolve(rows);
                }
            }); 
        }
      }); // getConnection
    }// fn
 } // getDepartments

getDepartments().then(function(rows){
  console.log(rows);    
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log(err); 
}).done(function(){
  pool.end();   // closing all connections in pool
});
```

Can I further improve the code? I have only used one Promise. Can I use multiple promises to avoid callback hell?

Answer (score 3):

Resource leakage: put `con.release()` outside the `else` block.

Comment: Would you need to release on an error?

Comment: @StephenRauch  Yes, as per the [documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections), you need to release on an error.